# How to move an item in a Scala Seq?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's say I have a case class like this:

```
case class Card(id: UUID, title: String)
```

and a Bucket class like this:

```
case class Bucket(id: UUID, title: String, cards: Seq[Card]) {
 def moveCard(cardId: UUID, newIndex: Int): Bucket = 
   copy(cards = {
    ???
  })
}
```

How would I fill in the moveCard() method to find the given card and move it to the new index in the sequence?

Comment: What goes in the index where the card was? Does it get swapped with the card currently at the `newIndex` location? Or is there an `empty` value to take its place (hopefully not `null`)? Or does that slot "disappear", i.e. everything gets shuffled to fill it in?

Comment: Everything should shuffle to fill in. i.e. if you move it from 1 to 4 in a sequence of 5 cards then 2->1, 3->2, 4->3. If you move from 4 to 1 in a sequence of 5 then 1->2, 2->3, 4->4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a double dose of `patch()` to move an item to a new location. Unfortunately it's a little different depending on the direction, forward or back.

```
case class Bucket(id: UUID, title: String, cards: Seq[Card]) {
  def moveCard(cardId: UUID, newIndex: Int): Bucket = {
    val from = cards.indexWhere(_.id == cardId)
    if (from < 0) throw new Error("no such card")
    copy(cards =
      if (from < newIndex)
        cards.patch(newIndex+1,Seq(cards(from)),0).patch(from,Seq(),1)
      else
        cards.patch(newIndex,Seq(cards(from)),0).patch(from+1,Seq(),1)
        )
  }
}
```

---

Or this very nice simplification offered by @LeoC:

```
copy(cards = cards.patch(from, Seq(), 1).patch(newIndex, Seq(cards(from)), 0))
```

Comment: Nice use of `patch`.  By first drawing the card then putting it back, I think the `copy` argument can be simplified to `cards = cards.patch(from, Seq(), 1).patch(newIndex, Seq(cards(from)), 0)` without condition.  Also think the special case of `newIndex == from` needs to be singled out.

Comment: @LeoC; many thanks! You're right, inserting first, before extracting, was backwards thinking. In the special case of `newIndex == from`, however, my code did the proper thing, which is nothing (in a rather complicated manner).

Comment: Nice job guys! I'll have to take figuring out what this is doing as my homework ;)